# JQuery: scrolling stops before reaching element

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery's scrollTop to scroll to a specific element but, weirdly, the scrolling stops before reaching the element. You can have a look a the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/acanana/pen/YXzVaL) I have made.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="events">
    <div id="event-list">
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Vendredi 17 octobre</h2>
            <ul id="event-1" class="event-title">
                list items
            </ul>
            <h2>Vendredi 21 octobre</h2>
            <ul id="event-2" class="event-title">
                list-items
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="event-details">
        <div class="content">
            <section id="event-1" class="details">
                stuff
            </section>

            <section id="event-2" class="details">
                stuff
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jquery:

```
$(function(){
  var thisOffset = $("#event-2").offset().top;
  console.log(thisOffset)

  $(".scroll").on("click", function(e){
    console.log("scroll")
     $("#event-details .content").animate({
       scrollTop: thisOffset
     }, 1000)
     e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Any idea why and how to solve this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only use 1 time the same `id` in a html page.
You use the `event-2` two times as `id`, so it scrolls only to the first one.

Comment: When using classes (updated codepen) it's the same problem. Using different class names in each div made it work. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

you actually have #event-2 twice in your code. That codepen scrolls to the first one as expected.

Comment: Same comment as above. Thank you!